# Reading files on local machine from docker container

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am running airflow from a docker image called puckel/docker-airflow.
I synchronized my local dags folder with container airflow folder when I started the container using following docker command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v <local_path>:/usr/local/airflow/dags puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

On my DAG I have a `PythonOperator` that calls a function named `start_script`, this function basically read and initialization files to extracts some information (for example passwords).
The function is as follows:

```
def start_script():
    config_parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config_parser.read("C:/dags/file.ini")
    pwd= config_parser.get("LOGS", "pwd")
```

When I run this function locally, the function is able to read the file and bring the password, unfortunatly when I run on docker with dags test command it returns the follow error:

```
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'LOGS'
```

What is the correct way to call for files in my local machine from a container?
I really think that when I run the function on container the function is not recognizing the path that config_parser should read.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you use /usr/local/airflow/dags/file.ini as config path in Docker?

Comment: /usr/local/airflow/dags is the standard dags path of puckel/docker-airflow. I don't know how to check what is the config path. Could you inform what is the command to check it?

Comment: What is `<local_path>` in your command?

Comment: <local_path> is the folder where I save my DAGs on my machine: C:/dags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the container, you have to point to the config file in the mounted volume, so change `config_parser.read("C:/dags/file.ini")` to `config_parser.read("/usr/local/airflow/dags/file.ini")`.